# Download Laravel Installer error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, php-ini

While using this command I got this error. How can I fix it?

```
php composer.phar global require "laravel/installer"
```

Console output:

```
Changed current directory to /home/jiten-p/.config/composer
Using version ^1.5 for laravel/installer
./composer.json has been created

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Installation request for laravel/installer ^1.5 -> satisfiable by laravel/installer[v1.5.0].


    - laravel/installer v1.5.0 requires ext-zip * -> the requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.


  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:


    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini


  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.


Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.***
```

Comment: When posting here, please try to use real English words, avoid txtspk, and refrain from requesting special treatment. This is not a chat-room, and your audience are volunteers.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

According to composer error message you need to install php module `ext-zip`.

run `sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip`

It will andding php module `ext-zip` to your linux packages.

Comment: thx uh so much @J. Litvak i used this command its works thx a lot

Comment: Please mark my answer as useful. click up arrow @JitenPatel

Comment: i will give you + 1 but just please put more description to your soultion, otherwise your answer will landing in the low quality post and it will be deleted